How to render a RazorPage (a PageModel) to Html or how to nest Razor Pages
As weird as may sound, is it possible to render a Razor Page (a PageModel derived class) to Html?
To give you an idea of why I'd need this, I'm looking for ways to try nest Razor Pages.
For example, if I have a ParentModel : PageModel and a ChildModel: PageModel, I'd like to be able to put Child.cshtml somehow in the Parent.cshtml.
So for this, I'm first exploring the idea of how to render the ChildModel as a partial view.
EDIT: I'm fully aware of both partial views and ViewComponents. I don't like these solutions because I cannot use a Razor Page anymore. If that child view has some POST actions, I'm forced to put those actions in the parent ParentModel (or somewhere else) which I don't like.

I'd advise just encapsulating what you can in partial views and then rendering them where you need it. Sounds like your problem could be solved with partial views.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-8.0

@Prolog I edited my question, I'm aware of the partial views and view components.

@poul-bak I edited my question, I'm aware of the partial views and view components.

According to your description, I think view component is a better choice than the partial views.
From doc:
View components are similar to partial views, but they're much more powerful. View components don't use model binding, they depend on the data passed when calling the view component.
It also support the viewbag and support inject the service into it which are more similar with the normal razor page.
More details about how to use it, you could refer to this example:
Child class:
public class ChildModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

Component class:
public class ChildViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string someParameter)
    {
        var model = new ChildModel { Id = 1 };
        return View(model);
    }
}

Create a view as below path :
Please notice: the view component view path need match as below:
/Views/{Controller Name}/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}
/Views/Shared/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}
/Pages/Shared/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}
/Areas/{Area Name}/Views/Shared/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}

So you need create it as below:
Views/Shared/Components/Child/Default.cshtml
View:
@model ChildModel

<div>
    <!-- Child content goes here -->
    <h2>@Model.Id</h2>
</div>

Usage inside the parent page:
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Child", new ChildModel { Id = 1 })


Thank you. I'm fully aware of both partial views and ViewComponents. I don't like these solutions because I cannot use a Razor Page anymore. If that child view has some POST actions, I'm forced to put those actions in the parent ParentModel (or somewhere else) which I don't like.

Using the ajax with the web api may solve the issue.

I was looking for a server side solution.

So now you just want to render the razor page's html inside the another razor pages which means you need customize the razor page's render method to achieve your requirement.

Never seen that anywhere. Do you have an example? Which method you mean exactly and how it will work? I think I read somewhere Razor Pages are not meant to be nested.
